# Assign number from Database

Tags: php, pdo

I am making a site with some ranks. If someone will click on a button, the user will be a higher rank. I have created a databse with number like: https://gyazo.com/a18204ac1845924712b86e9081da37b3

So, each rank does have a number. I want to count up 1 number from the field `nummer` each time. Just like: I am Gevorderd Agent 1, so my nummer is 4. I want to count one number up, so 5. Then I want to echo the rang with the nummer 5, so Gevorderd Agent 2.

I have heard about `ORDER BY ASC LIMIT`. I tried to use that, but it isn't working.

My PHP:

```
<?php

include("connection.php");

$pdoResult = $pdoConnect->query("SELECT * FROM rangselect ORDER BY ASC LIMIT 1, 2");

foreach($pdoResult as $row) {
    echo $row['0'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed order by Column_name, for example:

```
SELECT column FROM table_name ORDER BY column  ASC|DESC;
```

You should try...

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$pdoResult = $pdoConnect->query("SELECT * FROM rangselect ORDER BY number ASC LIMIT 1, 2");
foreach($pdoResult as $row) {
    echo $row['0'];
}
?>
```